# Initializing a vector with class template of different / unknown types

Tags: c++, class, templates

Working on a command line parser for myself. I knew immediately that I was going to have trouble with this construct and hoping someone could provide suggestions for a work around.

I want to store the argument list of parameters (based off a template) in a `vector` that will possibly contain a variety of different data types. But from my understanding, you have to define the `vector<template<type>>` statically. Is there a way to except multiple types?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

namespace clparser
{
    class CommandLine {
    private:
        std::vector<Parameter<AnyType??>*> ArgumentList;

    public:

        void Add(Parameter<AnyType??>* Parameter) { ArgumentList.push_back(Parameter); }
    };


    template<typename T>
    class Parameter {
    private:
        const char *ShortOption;
        const char *LongOption;
        const char *Description;
        const bool RequiredField;
        const char *DefaultValue;


    public:
        Parameter(const char *ShortOption, const char *LongOption, const char *Description, const bool RequiredField, const char *DefaultValue)
            : ShortOption(ShortOption), LongOption(LongOption), Description(Description), RequiredField(RequiredField), DefaultValue(DefaultValue)
        {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe `boost::any`?

Comment: I would prefer to not have any boost dependencies but if I can't accomplish this with the STL... Thanks though

Comment: Since c++17 `any` will be also available in `std`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: If you know the types, consider using std::variant

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a C++11 solution, I propose you a iper-simplified version from my command line parser. Hoping that can be of inspiration for you.

The idea behind my solution is the use of base/derived polymorphism: a pure virtual `class optBase` that is a base for a set of template classes dedicated to options (in the following example, only `class opt`; but there are other three in my parser).

Then the (not template) `class yData` contain a `std::unique_ptr<optBase>` (if you use a simple pointer to `optBase` you can compile in C++98 too, I suppose; but I suggest the use of C++11 or newer).

`class yData` correspond (roughly) to your tou your `class Parameter` but (here is the trick) isn't a template class; contain a base pointer to a template class.

My `class yarg` correspond to your `class clparser` and my `std::map<int, yData>  idMap` correspond (roughly) to your `std::vector<Parameter<AnyType??>*> ArgumentList`.

To feed `idMap`, I've developed a set of template method (one for every derived from `optbase` classes); in the following example you can see a iper-semplified version of one of them: `addOpt()` (corresponding, roughly, to your `Add()`).

In the following example you can see a little `main()` with a couple of uses for `addOpt()`: the first for a `int` parameter and the second for a `double` parameter (important (and weak point of my solution): the returned value *must* be saved in a *reference* variable, not in a simple variable).

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>


   class optBase
    { 
      public:
         // some pure virtual methods
    };

   template <typename X>
   class opt : public optBase
    {
      private:
         X    val { };
         // ...

      public:

         opt ()
          { }

         opt (X const & v0)
            : val { v0 } // ...
          { }

         X const & getVal () const
          { return val; }

         X & getVal ()
          { return val; }

         // ...
    };

   // other optBase derived classes (for flags, containers of values, etc)

   class yData
    {
      private:
         // ...
         std::unique_ptr<optBase>  optB;

      public:
         yData (/* other arguments */ std::unique_ptr<optBase> optB0)
            : /* something else */ optB { std::move(optB0) }
          { }
         // ...
         std::unique_ptr<optBase> const & getPnt () const
          { return optB; }
    };

   class yarg
    {
      private:
         // ...
         std::map<int, yData>  idMap;
         // ...

      public:
         // ...
         template <typename T>
         T & addOpt (/* other arguments */ T const &  def = T())
          {
            int      id   { /* some value */ };
            opt<T> * optP { nullptr };
            // ...&
            idMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                  std::forward_as_tuple(id),
                  std::forward_as_tuple(/* other arguments */
                     std::unique_ptr<optBase>(optP = new opt<T>(def))));

            return optP->getVal();
          }

    };

int main ()
 {
   yarg  y;

   // important: use a *reference*
   auto & pi = y.addOpt(3);   // pi is a int
   auto & pd = y.addOpt(3.0); // pd is a double

   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pi), int &>::value,    "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pd), double &>::value, "!!");
 }
```